# Spring mvc check if was BindingResult in javascript response

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

Is there a clear way to check if ajax success response controller returned view with validation errors?

controler:

```
if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return "place/add";
    }
```

javascript:

```
$.ajax({
        url : "<spring:url value="/place/add"/>",
        type : 'POST',
        data : $("#newPlaceForm").serialize(),
        success : function(response) {
```

How do I check if the response has no validation messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more clear to generate a HTTP response code to indicate the error.

For example: `response.sendError(400, "Validation failed")`

jQuery will execute the provided error handler based on the response code.

```
$.ajax( '/your/url').error(function (jqXHR) {
    if (jqXHR.status == 400) {
        console.log('Bad Request');
    }
});
```

This is more clear since handling **errors** in a **success** handler doesn't make much sense. The failed request is also easier to debug with your browsers developer tools.

Comment: but in this way I lost errors for `<form:errors path="*"></form:errors>`

Comment: In that case just use `response.setStatus(400)`

Comment: it's problematic now with `error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      
      $("#newLocationBox").html(xhr);
         alert(xhr.status)
     
          }` I can't replace div content with response

Comment: solved:  `$("#newLocationBox").html(xhr.responseText);`,

Ok, I accept your solution, but now I have 400 bad request in firebug, I handle it but it doesn't look nice

Comment: @donatello That's the whole point of setting the status to 400 ;) That it doesn't look nice in firebug is not important at all. The point is that the request has failed at some point and should be handled as such.

Answer (score 0):

> success : function(response){
>
> ```
> if(response.status == "SUCCESS"){
>
> // success code
>
> }else{
>     // show validation errors
>      errorInfo = "";
>      for(var i =0 ; i < response.result.length ; i++){
>         errorInfo += "<br>" + (i + 1) +". " + response.result[i].code;
>       }
>
>      $('#errorId').html("Please correct following errors: " + errorInfo);
>
> },  error: function(e){
>          alert('Error: ' + e);
>      }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with:

```
                success : function(response) {
                try {
                    var status = $.parseJSON(response);
                    if (status.status = 'OK') {
                        alertify.success("Akcja wykonana pomyślnie");
                        $("#newPlaceForm").hide();
                        $("#spotPlaces").show();
                    }

                } catch (e) {
                    $("#newLocationBox").html(response);
                }

            }
```

and it seems clear for me, I dont't have to search for errors in html code, if everything goes Ok I just return in controller view which only has ${status} field and I add attribute `status` as stringified Json `model.addAttribute("status", "{\"status\": \"OK\"}");`